# Does python threading.Lock() lock everything that needs locking?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multithreading

Script below is abstracted. My question is about the use of `threading.Lock()`

Locking limits access to "shared resources" but I am nervous about how far that goes. I have *objects attributes that are lists of objects which have attributes that are arrays* in this example. In some cases the dependency will go farther.

Does `Lock()` "know" for sure about everything that needs to be locked?

The output of the script below is also shown. The purpose of the script is mostly for discussion - It doesn't fail, but I am not confident that it is Locking everything it needs to.

```
start:   [array([0, 1]), array([0, 1, 2]), array([0, 1, 2, 3])]
append an object
done!
finish:  [array([505, 605]), array([10, 11, 12]), array([10, 11, 12, 13]), array([5])]


import time
from threading import Thread, Lock
import numpy as np

class Bucket(object):
    def __init__(self, objects):
        self.objects = objects

class Object(object):
    def __init__(self, array):
        self.array = array

class A(Thread):
    def __init__(self, bucket):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.bucket      = bucket
    def run(self):
        nloop            = 0
        locker           = Lock()
        n = 0
        while n < 10:
            with locker:  
                objects = self.bucket.objects[:]  # makes a local copy of list each time
            for i, obj in enumerate(objects):
                with locker:
                    obj.array += 1
                time.sleep(0.2)
            n += 1
            print 'n: ', n
        print "done!"
        return

objects = []
for i in range(3):
    ob = Object(np.arange(i+2))
    objects.append(ob)
bucket = Bucket(objects)

locker           = Lock()

a = A(bucket)
print [o.array for o in bucket.objects]

a.start()

time.sleep(3)

with locker:
    bucket.objects.append(Object(np.arange(1)))  # abuse the bucket!
    print 'append an object'
time.sleep(5)

print [o.array for o in bucket.objects]
```

Comment: FYI you want to share a lock between all threads. Currently as you have it each thread has it's own lock, which won't block other threads using their separate lock

Comment: @GP89 oh! So those are completely independent instances, right, yes I see.

Comment: Perhaps not the nicest code pattern, but removing `locker = Lock()` in `run()` would do it, as then the `locker` reference in `run()` would instead use the global one defined below, as it would no longer be shadowed

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you seem to misunderstand how a lock works.

a lock doesn't lock any objects, it can just lock the thread *execution*.

The first thread which tries to enter a `with locker:` block succeeds.

If another thread tries to enter a `with locker:` block (with the same `locker` object), it's delayed until the first thread exits the block, so both threads cannot change the value of the variable inside the block at the same time.

Here your "shared resources" are the variables you're changing in your blocks: as I can see, `objects` and `obj.array`. You're basically protecting them from concurrent access (that is - in a python version where there isn't a GIL for starters) *just because only one thread can change them at a time*

Old-timers call that a *critical section*, where only 1 thread can execute at a time.

Note that it's slightly dubious to use the same `locker` object for different resources. This has more chance to deadlock / be slower that it needs to be.

(and if you nest 2 `with locker` calls you get a deadlock - you need an RLock if you want to do that)

That's as simple as that.

Comment: Okay I think I'm almost there now. It's the use of the word "shared" in documentation that's throwing me off. Python doesn't check what is or isn't shared? Once a thread acquires a Lock, all threads are blocked even if they don't share data? Or is there some checking of what is shared and only some threads are blocked?

Comment: you cannot have 2 threads in the same with locker block at the same time. That is the protection. if no other thread tries to enter a with block, it runs without blocking.

Comment: Okay I really appreciate your explanation. Thank you! It's late here so I am going to re-read this again in the morning. I am sure it is a simple concept, but I'm being locked or blocked from understanding right now.

Comment: Oh! so if the arrays attached to those objects are accessed anywhere else, it's my job to hunt those bits of python down myself and make sure I also protect the arrays there, and with the same `with locker` instance. I think I've got it!

Comment: @uhoh Right- or better only access those bits in one place, that uses the lock. So you don't have to remember to use the lock every time you modify. For instance instead of accessing `obj.array` directly, maybe have `obj.addToArray(1)` which uses the locking inside the method

Comment: For some reason this answer gave me the best explanation of a thread lock. I understand better. Thank you.

Comment: The one thing that scares me about "with some_lock: codeblock" is the with doesn't guarentee a lock.aquire(). It just says if I DO aquire() a lock run "codeblock". But I have not read what happens anywhere explicidly stating what happens when you do not aquire() the lock with the "with" clause. This is when I would like the with:/else: structure.

Comment: +1 for the "*it's delayed until the first thread exits the block*"... This is exactly what I am looking for!

Answer (score 10):

A lock *doesn't know* any thing about you're trying to do. It's only a lock, it doesn't care where you put it on.

For example, you can declare:

```
lock = threading.Lock()
```

and then:

```
with lock:
    # Do stuff.

# In another thread
with lock:
    # Do something else
```

All other blocks with `with lock` cannot execute unless the current block is finished, it has nothing to do with what is in the block. So for this instance, assuming the first `#Do stuff` is running, when second thread hit `with lock: # Do something else`, it won't run because there's the same lock. Using `self.lock` is a good idea if you're doing object oriented programming.

Answer (score 2):

Better to say, multiprocessing Lock is not a lock, but a key.
If we have one key for several blocks of code, we can use it only to open one of them at once (lock or key acquire). While the key is busy, other blocks of code, that ask for the same key, can't be executed and will wait. So it only blocks some amount of code, stops interpretator from executing it.

Comment: Yes this makes sense to me, I recall being so confused by the term, struggling to see how it worked as a lock. Thanks for the helpful answer!